# .Formula VBA doesn't work, does anyone know why?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
.Cells(lLinha, 15).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(=INDEX([Data de monitoramento],MATCH(1,([@[Nome da tomadora]]=[Razão social / Nome])*([Papel na operação]="Tomadora"),0))"
```

> This VBA Formula doesn't work. I don't know why. Can someone help?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: That `=` before `INDEX` looks off. You need to double up the quotes around `Tomadora`. Seems like you're missing part(s) of the outer `VLOOKUP`, or you don't actually need the outer `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: You also need double quote inside your formula on stuff like `...="Tomadora")...` It becomes: `...=""Tomadora"")...`

Comment: Is it the `.Cells(lLinha, 15).Formula` part that is not working or the formula you are trying to insert?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your formula needs to be a valid formula.
2. You need to properly escape `"`.

So to point 1, `=VLOOKUP(=INDEX` is not a valid formula. To point 2, you need to escape the quotes around `Tomadora`.

Try this: `"=VLOOKUP(INDEX([Data de monitoramento],MATCH(1,([@[Nome da tomadora]]=[Razão social / Nome])*([Papel na operação]=""Tomadora""),0))"`